# Parsing html with page hash navigation

Tags: java, http, url

I have to parse an html page. I get it via url such as `"https://..bla-bla../final_page/#hash-command".` But JSoup gets page without `hash-command`, just `final_page`, but it's not the page i want to parse. How can I make a request to get the right responce? (I also tried to use okHttp to establish a connection, but it wasn't make any result).

Comment: The part after `#` is called a [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), and it is not part of the request URI that is sent to the server. It is purely **client-side**. Many pages use Javascript to change the page content/view based on the URI fragment. **JSoup** is an HTML parser, with no embedded browser engine. Hence, it cannot run the JS code responsible for showing the correct view based on the URI fragment.

Comment: @Aziz ok, thank you. So do you know some instuments can help me?

Comment: For Java, there is [**Selenium**](https://www.selenium.dev/) and [**HTMLUnit**](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/), among [many other options](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).